# How do I format a JSON result in ASP.NET Core MVC Web API?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Web API will return JSON automatically, but what if I want it in a different layout.  For example, if Web API returns,

```
[
    {
        "patron": 9,
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "book": {
            "book_id": 1,
            "patron": 9
        }
    },

    {
        "patron": 9,
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "book": {
            "book_id": 2,
            "patron": 9
        }
    },
    {
        "patron": 9,
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "book": {
            "book_id": 3,
            "patron": 9
        }
    }
]
```

but I want,

```
[
    {
        "patron": 9,
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "books": [
         {
            "book_id": 1,
            "patron": 9
         },
        {
            "book_id": 2,
            "patron": 9
        },
        {
            "book_id": 3,
            "patron": 9
        }

        ]
    }
]
```

Is there a way to do this without handwriting my JSON result?  I really don't wan to do that.

Answer (score 4):

The model you are returning needs an `IEnumerable` type for `books`.

Currently, the shape of your .NET model/JSON is:

```
public class Patron
{
    public int patron { get; set; }
    public int book_id { get; set; }
    public Book book { get; set; }
}
```

While the output you describe looks like this:

```
public class Patron
{
    public int patron { get; set; }
    public int book_id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Book> books { get; set; }
}
```